# AD B2C Forgot password - Navigate to Password page on verifying the code automatically instead of clicking the Continue button

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, forgot-password, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In AD B2C Forgot password user flow, is there any way to navigate to the Password page after verify the code automatically instead of clicking on the Continue button.

Now, we need to click the continue button after the code is verified to navigate to the new password setting page.

[image]

Comment: I am wondering the same thing on a split email verification flow, but not have found any resources that indicate we are able to automatically progress to the next Orchestration Step automatically upon verification. Since you asked this question have you found a solution? Only remote solution I have found is to use custom JavaScript, but have not found an implementation that illustrates this concept for this exact purpose.

Comment: I went with the javascript

Comment: Do you have an example of how you implemented this? Could be useful in the future.